# Osclass how to change a search text field to a dropdown with options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys i'm using osclass and need some help how to change a text box to a drop-down box with options on search!

This is the codes i have from the text field:

```
  <input placeholder="<?php osc_esc_html(_e('Price', 'ctg_housing')) ; ?> <?php osc_esc_html(_e('Min', 'ctg_housing')) ; ?>" type="text" id="priceMin" name="sPriceMin" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html(osc_search_price_min()); ?>" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />

  <input placeholder="<?php osc_esc_html(_e('Price', 'ctg_housing')) ; ?> <?php osc_esc_html(_e('Max', 'ctg_housing')) ; ?>" type="text" id="priceMax" name="sPriceMax" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html(osc_search_price_max()); ?>" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" />
```

This i need like option in the dropdown box:

```
<option value="5000">P5,000</option>
<option value="100001">P100,001</option>
<option value="300001">P300,001</option>
<option value="500001">P500,001</option>
<option value="1000001">P1,000,001</option>
```

Hope someone can help me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For bender theme.
Look in search-sidebar.php

Replace

```
<?php if( osc_price_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
<fieldset>
    <div class="row price-slice">
        <h3><?php _e('Price', 'bender') ; ?></h3>
        <span><?php _e('Min', 'bender') ; ?>.</span>
        <input class="input-text" type="text" id="priceMin" name="sPriceMin" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html(osc_search_price_min()); ?>" size="6" maxlength="6" />
        <span><?php _e('Max', 'bender') ; ?>.</span>
        <input class="input-text" type="text" id="priceMax" name="sPriceMax" value="<?php echo osc_esc_html(osc_search_price_max()); ?>" size="6" maxlength="6" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
<?php } ?>
```

with

```
<?php if( osc_price_enabled_at_items() ) { ?>
    <fieldset>
            <div class="row price-slice">
                <h3><?php _e('Price', 'bender') ; ?></h3>
                <div class="select-box undefined">
            <select id="priceMin" name="sPriceMin" style="opacity: 0;display:inline-block;width:45%;">
                        <?php $pmin=osc_esc_html(osc_search_price_min()); ?>
                        <option value="<?php osc_esc_html(_e('Price', 'bender')) ; ?> <?php osc_esc_html(_e('Min', 'bender')) ; ?>"></option>
                        <option value="5000" <?php if($pmin==5000) echo "selected"; ?> >P5,000</option>
                        <option value="100001" <?php if($pmin==100001) echo "selected"; ?> >P100,001</option>
                        <option value="300001" <?php if($pmin==300001) echo "selected"; ?> >P300,001</option>
                        <option value="500001" <?php if($pmin==500001) echo "selected"; ?> >P500,001</option>
                        <option value="1000001" <?php if($pmin==1000001) echo "selected"; ?> >P1,000,001</option>
                        </select><a href="#" class="select-box-trigger"><span class="select-box-label"></span><span class="select-box-icon">0</span></a>
        </div>
-
                <div class="select-box undefined">
            <select id="priceMax" name="sPriceMax" style="opacity: 0;display:inline-block;width:45%;">
                        <?php $pmax=osc_esc_html(osc_search_price_max()); ?>
                        <option value="<?php osc_esc_html(_e('Price', 'bender')) ; ?> <?php osc_esc_html(_e('Max', 'bender')) ; ?>"></option>
                        <option value="100000" <?php if($pmax==100000) echo "selected"; ?> >P10,000</option>
                        <option value="300000" <?php if($pmax==300000) echo "selected"; ?> >P300,000</option>
                        <option value="500000" <?php if($pmax==500000) echo "selected"; ?> >P500,000</option>
                        <option value="1000000" <?php if($pmax==1000000) echo "selected"; ?> >P1,000,000</option>
                        <option value="5000000" <?php if($pmax==5000000) echo "selected"; ?> >P5,000,000</option>
                        </select><a href="#" class="select-box-trigger"><span class="select-box-label"></span><span class="select-box-icon">0</span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
<?php } ?>
```

If you use ctg_housing replace all bender words from the code with ctg_housing.